# Get checkbox value of unchecked checkboxes in a table

Tags: javascript, html, dom, form

I have a table where a user can (un)check checkboxes among other features in each row.

I faced the problem that I don't receive unchecked checkboxes to my backend. 
This led to a bigger issue since every row should have synchronized fields of course.

For example:

- Row 1 - checked
- Row 2 - unchecked
- Row 3 - checked

My backend receives now an array like this:

`clickBoxReduce
[true, true]`

Backend-Function *like* this

```
@PostMapping()
public String selectPost(
        @RequestParam(required = false, name = "clickboxReduce") String[] clickboxReduce,
        Model model) {
    System.out.println("clickBoxReduce");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(clickboxReduce));
    return "fillDetails";
}
```

Obviously I cannot see **which** row exactly is unchecked.

My solution was to give each input tag a value `no`and `yes` and update this value with every checkbox click.

```
function handleClickOnReduceStart (element) {
  if (element.value === 'yes') {
    element.value = 'no'
  } else if (element.value === 'no') {
    element.value = 'yes'
  }
}
```

And set all checkboxes on checked before submitting the form with the function `interceptSubmit` blow. 
With that I get all checkbox values in the correct order.

It is visible for the user that the checkboxes change again if there is a slight delay what is not so good.

Does anyone have a better idea?

Here the table:

```
<!--- start table -->
<div class="container">
    <br>
    <h4 style="text-align: center">Please specify below</h4>
    <br>
    <form method="POST" id="postDetails" onsubmit="return interceptSubmit()">
        <table id="buyTable" class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Brand</th>
                <th>Buy-Price</th>
                <th>Bottom</th>
                <th>Top</th>
                <th>Stop</th>
                <th>Reduce</th>
                <th>Start</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr th:each="car : ${cars}">
                <td>
                    <select th:id="${car.getBrand()}" title="selectBuyOrSell" onchange="updateBuyTable(this)">>
                        <option value="buy">Buy</option>
                        <option value="sell">Sell</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a th:text="${car.getBrand()}"></a><input type="hidden" name="brandBuy"
                                                              th:value="${car.getBrand()}"/>
                </td>
                <td><input type="number" step="0.00000001" placeholder="Enter price"
                           name="buyPrice"/></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="0.00000001" placeholder="Enter bottom"
                           name="bottom"/></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="0.00000001" placeholder="Enter top"
                           name="top"/></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="0.00000001" placeholder="Enter stop"
                           name="stop"/></td>
                <td>
                    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                        <input id="clickboxReduce" name="clickboxReduce" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input"
                               value="yes"
                               onchange="handleClickOnReduceStart(this)" checked>
                        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                        <input id="clickboxStart" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input"
                               onchange="handleClickOnReduceStart(this)" checked>
                        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <!--                <td><input id="clickboxReduce" type="checkbox"></td>
                                <td><input id="clickboxStart" type="checkbox"></td>-->
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <button style="float: right!important;" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Continue</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

and the function

```
function interceptSubmit () {
  let form = document.getElementsByClassName('custom-control-input')

  for (i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
    if (!form[i].checked) {
      console.log('unchecked')
      form[i].checked = true
    }
  }
  return true // return false to cancel form action
}
```

Output of my backend controller

`clickBoxReduce
[yes, no, yes]`

Comment: You could just give the check boxes different names. Every row (car?) needs/should have a unique identifier, so for example `th:name="${'clickboxReduce_' + car.id}"`.

Comment: Additionally, why use “yes” or “no” when true/false already have a binary representation? Just a thought. For example with JavaScript `!!+”0”` equals false and `!!+”1”` equals true. Don’t you think it would be easier to maintain and require less logic and take up less data using 0 & 1? I’m sure java has a typecast equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your question

> *Does anyone have a better idea?*

There are multiple posts on SO like [Force a checkbox to always submit, even when unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3746678/1575353), which has [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6621928/1575353) that suggests adding a hidden input with the same name as the checkbox and the opposite value (e.g. "*no*").

> ```
> <input type="hidden" name="checkbox1" value="off">
> ```

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="on"> My checkbox
```

Perhaps you should consider using different elements - e.g. radio buttons, which can be [styled like more modern toggle inputs (e.g. iOS style)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37769450/1575353)

### Review of existing code

Looking at `interceptSubmit()` I see that:

- **Lines aren't terminated with semi-colons**. While they are only required [after a handful of statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion), it could lead to errors if somehow whitespace got removed.
- **The variable name `form` is slightly misleading** - typically a *form* refers to a `<form>` element, but in this case the variable is an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of elements with a particular class name, which appears to be two checkboxes with the given HTML.

  > ```
  > let form = document.getElementsByClassName('custom-control-input')
  > ```

  A more appropriate name might be `customControlInputs`
- **`form` isn't re-assigned** so it could be declared with `const` to avoid [accidental re-assignment and other bugs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/278653/244085).
- **`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a Live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)</sup>** so that assignment can take place outside of the function - perhaps an ideal place would be as soon as the DOM is ready
- **`for` loop variable `i` is a global variable** because it is not declared with `var`, `let`, etc. In general [it is best to avoid global variables](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil).
- **a [`for...of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) could be used** instead of a regular `for` loop if [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) is supported by all target browsers. That would allow simplification of accessing elements of the collection.